# constant blue screens on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bsod, crash

Windows 10

Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4460  CPU @ 3.20GHz, 3201 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 4 Logical

Adapter: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600

8gb ram

System Type: x64-based PC

Storage: SSD 120GB

All the [dmp files](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/mhdc7hdlukn51koq4yhq7/h?rlkey=o8s30smqj4qhooo3ojbezf0oj&dl=0) I could get (some crashes didn't have one, or had empty dmp files)

I've been having constant crashes on my pc, most of the time with a blue screen. Occasionally it simply shuts down and sometimes won't turn on properly after unless I turn it off and back on manually. The crashes are relatively inconsistent, sometimes I have multiple in an hour and sometimes none for 8 hours or so, even though I'm on the same apps/games that I am even when it does crash.

I've checked dmp files (I'm not knowledgeable at all, so I just googled some stuff in them), and results mostly told me I should update drivers. I checked windows update, device manager and the intel page and all said there are no available updates for my drivers. I've also done sfc scan (multiple times across the past 3 days), no issues there. I tried using blue screen troubleshooter, however it is not available on my pc.

All the crashes in the dmp files have been in the past 3 days, and sometimes I even get blue screens right as the pc turns on with 1 empty dmp file once it turns back on.

Comment: Often continuous BSODs on Windows 10 were related to Windows 8 drivers, especially those from Broadcom, being installed when legacy drivers were never updated for Windows 10. It really is pointless to troubleshoot this type of issue, unless you know exactly what the issue is because it takes more time to troubleshoot than reinstalling Windows and all software. First try a repair install by extracting a Windows install ISO to a directory, then running `setup.exe` _while booted to Windows_.

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ If it BSODs during the repair install, boot from a Windows install USB to do a clean install, reinstalling Windows to the same partition _without_ formatting - it will move everything from the root of `C:` to `C:\Windows.old`. If clean installing is required, reinstall CPU-related drivers _(chipset, IMEI, thermal, etc.)_ **prior to** running Windows Update, and software should only be installed once all drivers have been installed through Windows update or separately through their requisite installers

Comment: a BSOD could be faulty hardware, such as a failing SSD or powersupply. If you have backups, I would reinstall windows to see if the problem goes away. If not, test with other hardware. Replacing the SSD is easiest.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do any of this, is there a place where I can find a more detailed explanation/step-by-step?

Comment: Any information on the BSOD would help us help you, but as it currently stands, you haven’t provided any information to help you solve your problem. I won’t provide information on how to Reset your Windows installation since that’s far to often a solution offered on the website and often is an overkill solution to a problem that can actually be solved with a little diagnostic work

Comment: I've added all the dmp files, do those not contain enough information? I'm adding a new one in a bit, since I had another BSOD earlier.

Comment: @Ramhound Do you have access to the DMP files attached to the original post just fine, or do I need to change anything?

Comment: I'd rather not wait a week or more and pay money for something that could be relatively easy to fix myself, if I'm being honest.

Comment: @JoeyTMOG - I will provide feedback on a WinDBG analysis, but I won’t run WinDBG myself, on someone’s dump files. It’s up to you to narrow down which memory dumps are applicable. Especially which it’s like 12 memory dumps

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded your dumps and I'm a bit surprised by the number of
different crashes that you received.

This is a partial list :

- Bug Check 0x1A: MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
  a severe memory management error occurred.
- Bug Check 0x3B: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
  an exception happened while executing a routine that transitions from non-privileged code to privileged code.
- Bug Check 0x50: PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
  indicates that invalid system memory has been referenced.
- Bug check 0x1E: KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
  indicates that a kernel-mode program generated an exception that the error handler didn't catch.

All the crashes happen inside the Windows kernel, and don't seem
to be instigated by any device driver.

The most likely explanation I can think of is a bad memory.
So I would suggest to:

- Examine the Event Viewer for more error messages
- Run [Memtest86+](https://www.memtest.org/)
  for many hours, perhaps overnight. This will test the RAM, but also the
  general functioning of the memory controller and the CPU.

If Memtest86+ finds an error, you will need to locate the bad
RAM stick, and the method will depend on your motherboard model.

Comment: If the issue is likely RAM sticks, could I just replace those? I have some old PCs that no longer work with leftover parts, I could check if they're compatible although I doubt it. Also, do I need to do anything special before running memtest?

I did also check event viewer, saw some errors like this:

The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x0000001a (0x0000000000041790, 0xffffec000430b000, 0x000000000000000c, 0x000000000000000d). A dump was saved in: C:\WINDOWS\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 09ad9a35-1e66-427e-9470-6983c099aa11.

Comment: @JoeyTMOG - You would need to verify they are compatible with your hardware. 4th generation Intel hardware would be DDR3. Your information in your comment isn’t helpful, it’s unformatted, so it’s not possible to read. Verify a memory problem exists before doing anything

Comment: I do have 2 4gb DDR3 sticks from my old PC, should I try using them and see if the issue persists?

Comment: It would be better to run the tests first, to verify that the problem is indeed the RAM. Then if you have multiple RAM sticks, try to find the bad one by booting with less stick(s). Finally, it's best to replace the bad one with RAM that's identical to the other stick(s).